# redirection after drag and drop image upload using dropzonejs in php

Tags: php, dropzone.js

Is it possible to **redirect** to an another page ,after drag and drop image upload using dropzonejs in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely is !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dz"); // this will create instance of Dropzone on the #dz element
        myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            location.href = 'http://redirect-here/';  // this will redirect you when the file is added to dropzone
        });
    });
</script>
```

with the corresponding HTML

```
<form id="dz" ....
```